# wslで新規にubuntuを始める方法

Tags: ubuntu, wsl

## 概要

wslを実機に導入してしばらくubuntuを使っていたんですが、だいぶ環境を汚染してしまい、また新しく環境を作成したいです。ただ、今の環境はアーカイブとして残しておきたいと思っています。

wslの操作に疎く、`wsl install Ubuntu`など下手に打ってwindows側の環境を汚したらと思うと怖いので自分自身ではあまり操作できていません…

つまるところ

1. 今のディストリビューションをアーカイブして残しておく方法
2. Ubuntuをwslにクリーンインストールする方法

を教えていただきたいです。

## 参考

[グチャグチャになった「Ubuntu on WSL2」のやり直し方](https://qiita.com/PoodleMaster/items/b54db3608c4d343d27c4)
今の環境を消したいわけじゃないんです…

### wslバージョン

WSL バージョン: 1.2.5.0
カーネル バージョン: 5.15.90.1
WSLg バージョン: 1.0.51
MSRDC バージョン: 1.2.3770
Direct3D バージョン: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore バージョン: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows バージョン: 10.0.22621.2506

```
  NAME         STATE           VERSION
* ubuntu002    Stopped         2
  Ubuntu       Stopped         2
```

Comment: 「WSL Ubuntu 複数」で検索するだけでも解説記事がいくつか出てくるので、まずはそれらに目を通してみてください。

Answer (score -1):

インストール可能なディストリビューションを調べます。
ホスト(Windows)のPowerShellまたはcmdから次のコマンドを実行します。

```
wsl --list --online
```

出力例

```
NAME                                   FRIENDLY NAME
Ubuntu                                 Ubuntu
Debian                                 Debian GNU/Linux
kali-linux                             Kali Linux Rolling
Ubuntu-18.04                           Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Ubuntu-20.04                           Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Ubuntu-22.04                           Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
OracleLinux_7_9                        Oracle Linux 7.9
OracleLinux_8_7                        Oracle Linux 8.7
OracleLinux_9_1                        Oracle Linux 9.1
openSUSE-Leap-15.5                     openSUSE Leap 15.5
SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-15-SP4    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP4
SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-15-SP5           SUSE Linux Enterprise 15 SP5
openSUSE-Tumbleweed                    openSUSE Tumbleweed
```

管理者でPowerShellまたはcmdからを起動し、以下のコマンドを実行します。

```
wsl --install -d 【ディストリビューション】
wsl --set-default 【ディストリビューション】
```

【ディストリビューション】は`wsl --list --online`の実行結果NAMEで示される名前です。

例）Ubuntu 22.04 LTSをインストールする場合

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu-22.04
wsl --set-default Ubuntu-22.04
```

インストールされた【ディストリビューション】を確認します。

```
wsl --list  --verbose
```

先日Ubuntu-22.04をインストールしたとき既存の【ディストリビューション】は残っていいましたが、重要なファイルは退避しておいた方がよいと思います。